# Problema con Angular 8 y visualizacion

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

buen día a todos, he tenido hace tiempo este problema y no he podido resolverlo, lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de clientes basado en Angular cli 8, y PHP, del lado de PHP funciona todo perfecto, pero al momento de estar en el Front, con angular no se visualiza correctamente, adjunto imagenes:

[image: Así se tiene que ver]

Se tendría que ver de ese modo, pero al momento de iniciar sesión en la página de Login, y que angular dirija a /Dashboard, aparece en la siguiente manera:

[image: Imagen PWA]

Así de esa manera me muestra el sitio y para que se muestre correctamente tengo que actualizar y lo muestra correctamente.

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

> - src
> - - app
> - - - app.component.html
> - - - app.component.ts
> - - - app.module.ts
> - - - app-routing.module.ts
> - - - app.component.css
> - - - Pages
> - - - - Login
> - - - - - login.component.ts
> - - - - - login.component.css
> - - - - - login.component.html
> - - - - Dashboard
> - - - - - dashboard.component.ts
> - - - - - dashboard.component.html
> - - - - - dashboard.component.css
> - - - assets

El codigo del Routing es:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './Pages/login/login.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './Pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {TransaccionesComponent} from './Pages/transacciones/transacciones.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/Login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'Transacciones', component: TransaccionesComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

El codigo del index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Favicon icon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
  <title>Login - Area de clientes</title>
  <!-- chartist CSS -->
  <link href="assets/libs/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/libs/chartist-plugin-tooltips/dist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--c3 CSS -->
  <link href="assets/libs/morris.js/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/extra-libs/c3/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/extra-libs/calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- All Required js -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->

  <div class="chat-windows"></div>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- All Jquery -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- apps -->
  <script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.init.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app-style-switcher.js"></script>
  <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
  <!--Wave Effects -->
  <script src="assets/js/waves.js"></script>
  <!--Menu sidebar -->
  <script src="assets/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
  <!--Custom JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>
  <!-- This Page JS -->
  <script src="assets/libs/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/pages/chartist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/extra-libs/c3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/extra-libs/c3/c3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/pages/dashboards/dashboard1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/pages/calendar/cal-init.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 650);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En el app.component.html solo esta esto:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

En el Login.component.html esta el codigo del formulario asi como en el archivo dashboard solo esta el codigo del dashboard, les dejo un link para que vean el error que hay en video, muchas gracias: https://youtu.be/cg-4uV4w3Dg , Olvidaba algo, la plantilla la compre en themeforest y la probe normalmente y funciona sin problema, y con php tambien funciona muy bien.

Añado el codigo del Dashboard.component.html:

```
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Main wrapper - style you can find in pages.scss -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- Left Sidebar - style you can find in sidebar.scss  -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- End Left Sidebar - style you can find in sidebar.scss  -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- Page wrapper  -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="page-breadcrumb border-bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12 align-self-center">
          <h5 class="font-medium text-uppercase mb-0">Dashboard</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-xs-12 align-self-center">
          <button class="btn btn-danger text-white float-right ml-3 d-none d-md-block">Buy Ample Admin</button>
          <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-2 float-md-right float-left">
            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 justify-content-end p-0">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Bread crumb and right sidebar toggle -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Container fluid  -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <div class="page-content container-fluid">
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <!-- Card Group  -->
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card p-2 p-lg-3">
          <div class="p-lg-3 p-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger text-white btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="ti-clipboard"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="ml-4" style="width: 38%;">
                <h4 class="font-light">Total Projects</h4>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="40"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-auto">
                <h2 class="display-7 mb-0">23</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card p-2 p-lg-3">
          <div class="p-lg-3 p-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <button class="btn btn-circle btn-cyan text-white btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="ti-wallet"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="ml-4" style="width: 38%;">
                <h4 class="font-light">Total Earnings</h4>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-cyan" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="40"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-auto">
                <h2 class="display-7 mb-0">76</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card p-2 p-lg-3">
          <div class="p-lg-3 p-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <button class="btn btn-circle btn-warning text-white btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="ml-4" style="width: 38%;">
                <h4 class="font-light">Total Earnings</h4>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="40"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-auto">
                <h2 class="display-7 mb-0">83</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <!-- Products yearly sales, Weather Cards Section  -->
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Products Yearly Sales</h5>
              <ul class="list-inline dl mb-0 float-right">
                <li class="list-inline-item text-info"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> Mac</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item text-danger"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> Windows</li>
              </ul>
              <div id="ct-visits" style="height: 320px;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-danger">
              <div id="ct-daily-sales" style="height: 304px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div>
                  <h2 class="font-medium">Week Sales</h2>
                  <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-0">Ios app - 160 sales</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-auto">
                  <button class="btn btn-circle btn-info text-white btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <!-- User Table & Profile Cards Section  -->
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase mb-0">Manage Users</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table no-wrap user-table mb-0">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium pl-4">#</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium">Occupation</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium">Email</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium">Category</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 text-uppercase font-medium">Manage</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">1</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Daniel Kristeen</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">2</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Emma Smith</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">3</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Olivia Johnson</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">4</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Isabella Williams</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">5</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Sophia Jones</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="pl-4">6</td>
                  <td>
                    <h5 class="font-medium mb-0">Charlotte Brown</h5>
                    <span class="text-muted">Texas, Unitedd states</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">Visual Designer</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">Past : teacher</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="text-muted">daniel@website.com</span><br>
                    <span class="text-muted">999 - 444 - 555</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                      <option>Modulator</option>
                      <option>Admin</option>
                      <option>User</option>
                      <option>Subscriber</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle"><i class="ti-trash"></i> </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-circle btn-lg btn-circle ml-2"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Container fluid  -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- footer -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <footer class="footer text-center">
      All Rights Reserved by Ample admin. Designed and Developed by
      <a href="https://wrappixel.com">WrapPixel</a>.
    </footer>
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End footer -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->
  </div>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- End Page wrapper  -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Wrapper -->
```

Comment: He visto que el directorio se llama `Login` y se referencia como `login` en los `import`, imagino que habrás hecho igual con otros directorios de JavaScript o código PHP. Eso funcionará en una máquina de pruebas en Windows, pero si lo subes a un hosting (que probablemente sea Linux) no te funcionará. ¿Podrías darnos la URL para entrar a la página y ver qué está fallando? (Los mensajes de la consola de depuración lo suelen decir todo).

Comment: Qué tal, muchas gracias, pero estoy desarrollando en Mac Os Mojave, y el IDE que utilizo es PHPStorm, y el hace las importaciones en automático, y no me da ningún error, excepto el de la visualización.

Comment: Pues es raro que te funcione el `import {LoginComponent} from './Pages/login/login.component';` si la ruta al archivo es `./Pages/Login/login.component.ts`. Aún así sólo con un vídeo de apenas 5 segundos y un par de capturas de pantalla no tenemos información acerca de qué está pasando. Como mínimo deberías compartir el código que implementa `DashboardComponent`.

Comment: Ok, ya adjunte el codigo del dashboard component, y el tipeo del Login es por que el archivo no tiene que ver con el nombre del modulo, ya que en el modulo esta tipificado con Mayusculas y en el archivo con minuscula, al colocar el comando ng g c Pages/Login angular te crean los archivos con minuscula pero la clase con mayusculas.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza en responder. Recuerda responder nombrándome poniendo un @ delante para que me llegue una notificación. Sólo a los autores de preguntas o respuestas le llega notificación de manera automática (le nombres o no). ¿Sigues con el problema o lo solucionaste?